# Need help creating 1 MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a message board. When a topic gets a reply, the entire topic (all rows that has the topicid) must be bumped to the top of the forum. Pinned topics should always be displayed first, then followed by the topic that has the most recent post date because they are bumped to the top when they get a reply.

This is a pic of the table that contains the posts.

[DB Table before query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg3wN.jpg)
I need 1 query that will do the following:

1. group all the topicid together (lets call this "group");
2. within each group sort the rows by parentid ascending, but NULL always is sorted first;
3. groups that are "pinned" are displayed first
4. then groups that have the "latest" post displayed first

The query should give the following results

[Results of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gef9.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query will do what you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m
ORDER BY IF(pinned='yes','9999-12-31 23:59:59', (SELECT MAX(date) FROM messages m2 WHERE m2.topicid = m.topicid)) DESC,
         topicid, IFNULL(parentid, 0)
```

The first part of the order by ensures that groups that are pinned are ordered first, followed by groups that have the most recent post. It does this by selecting the maximum possible date when the group is pinned, otherwise the latest date for posts in that group and sorts by that value descending. The second part then sorts those posts by topicid, and the final part sorts by parentid. To ensure that posts with a NULL parentid sort first, we use an IFNULL clause on parentid to set the sorting value to 0 when parentid is NULL.

I've created an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/440ce8/3) to demonstrate this.

**Edit** This updated query will also sort pinned topics by latest date instead of just by topicid. It does this by adding 1000 years to the date of pinned posts, thus ensuring that pinned posts sort ahead of non-pinned posts while retaining the ordering between pinned posts as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages m
ORDER BY (SELECT MAX(IF(pinned='yes', date + interval 1000 year, date)) 
          FROM messages m2 
          WHERE m2.topicid = m.topicid) DESC,
   topicid, ifnull(parentid, 0)
```

Here's an updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c91c0/1) to demonstrate.

Comment: Not bad at all! But I also want to sort the pinned topics on the  "latest" post. So within all the pinned topics I want to display the topic that has the latest post first. In your query all pinned topics has latest post "9999-12-31 23:59:59" so the query just orders the pinned topic by the topic id.

Comment: Hi @Farliesz see my edit. This new query will retain ordering on pinned posts too.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can only answer parts of your question, but I'm giving it a shot and posting it anyway in the hope that it will help you solve your issue.

First, I'd grab the pinned messages (lastest first in this query):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE pinned = 1 ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then, you can grab - let's say - the 10 most recent topics:

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS latest, topicid FROM messages GROUP BY topicid ORDER BY latest DESC LIMIT 10
```

Now you should know the `topicid`s from which you want to display messages. You could "chain together" the messages with a join:

```
SELECT * FROM messages AS m1 JOIN messages AS m2 ON m1.postid = m2.parentid WHERE m1.topicid IN <some stuff here> ORDER BY m1.topicid ASC, m1.postid DESC
```

Sorry for the incomplete answer. Any comments to help me fill the gaps are welcome ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can do this with multiple queries, but I was wondering if I could do this with only 1 query.